# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","

Tags: activerecord

I'm having some trouble with an Activerecord query. My current code looks like this:

```
Table1.select(
  '"table1"*, CASE WHEN "table2"."id" = null THEN 0 WHEN "table2"."foo" = "yes" THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS table2_status'
).from("table1").joins("table2").where(table3_id: object_from_table3.id)
```

When I run this in pry (breakpoint to irb basically), I'm getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
```

This is my first time constructing a complex query like this in Activerecord, and I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm not super experienced with SQL either. I'm probably just missing something simple, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The `from("table1").joins("table2")` forms some bad SQL.

```
"SELECT \"table1\"*, 
CASE 
  WHEN \"table2\".\"id\" = null THEN 0 
  WHEN \"table2\".\"foo\" = \"yes\" THEN 1 
  ELSE 2
END AS table2_status 
FROM table1 table2 // this part is invalid 
WHERE \"table1\".\"table3_id\" = 1299"
```

I ended up doing this instead:

```
Table1
  .select('"table1"*, CASE WHEN "table2"."id" = null THEN 0 WHEN "table2"."foo" = "yes" THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS table2_status')
  .from('"table1" LEFT OUTER JOIN "table2" ON "table2"."table1_id" = "stances"."id"')
  .where(table3_id: object_from_table3.id)
```

This formed the SQL correctly.